# Unwanted Type string appended in Computed Index field

Tags: solr, indexing, computed-field

I am creating computed index field for a Multilist field and want to return the items as String in a comma separated list.

However after indexing the Solr, an type text is getting appended to the result.

Configuration:

```
<field fieldName="category" returnType="string" />
```

I've also set the fully qualified name of the below class in the configuration.

[image]

Code I've written:

```
    public class CategoryMultilistField : IComputedIndexField
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }

        public virtual object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
        {
            var scIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

            if(scIndexable != null)
            {
                var item = (Item)scIndexable;

                if(item != null)
                {
                    MultilistField f = item.Fields["category"];                   

                    if (f != null)
                    {
                        var multilist = f.GetItems();
                        if (multilist == null || multilist.Length == 0)
                            return null;

                        return string.Join(",", multilist.Select(t => t[2]));
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `multilist.Select(t => t[2])`? Shouldn't it be `multilist.Select(t => t.Name)` or something like that?

Comment: @MarekMusielak - The name is coming as empty string. That's why I made this as t[2] which is giving me valid text.

Comment: Are you using SXA?

Comment: @Gatogordo - Yes, I am using SXA

Answer (score 3):

As you are using SXA, why not use the "ootb" option to add extra fields that include data from a linked item:

The doc here is talking about facets, but the main purpose is actually creating an index field: 
https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/extend-search.html#UUID-3cbc7b12-9aed-f7d2-cd98-fcca239042ee_id__Extend_search_to_3

> Add the following definition to your search configuration file:

```
<field fieldName="categorytext" returnType=”stringCollection” type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks,     Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" referenceField="category" contentField="title"/>
```

> where:
>
> fieldName – defines the index field name where the value will be
>   stored. Make sure this name differs from the reference field name.
>
> returntype – defines the return type for your computed field.
>
> referenceField – defines the field name on the indexed item.
>
> contentField – defines the field on the referenced item from which the
>   value will be retrieved during the indexing.

This way you don't need to write your own code, and this works for string collections. I didn't test the result if you want a string as returntype but I would give this a go...

Comment: Thank you @Gatogordo let me check this.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the index on the item, try to use either the field name or the field ID to get exactly what you want.

```
return string.Join(",", multilist.Select(t => t.Fields["My Field Name"].Value).Where(x => !string.IsNullorEmpty(x)));
```

**OR**

```
var fieldID = new ID("{19C00FAC-DB88-4634-B002-94742C2DE715}");
// ... code here ...
return string.Join(",", multilist.Select(t => t.Fields[fieldID].Value).Where(x => !string.IsNullorEmpty(x)));
```